# Avoid empty elements in match when optional substrings are not present

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I am trying to create a regex that match the strings returned by `diff` terminal command.

These strings start with a decimal number, might have a substring composed by a comma and a number, then a mandatory character (`a`, `c`, `d`) another mandatory decimal number followed by another optional group as the one before.

Examples:

```
27a27
27a27,30
28c28
28,30c29,31
1d1
1,10d1
```

I am trying to extract all the groups separately but the optional ones without `,`.

I am doing this in C++:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include <regex>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

  string t = "47a46";
  std::string result;
  std::regex re2("(\\d+)(?:,(\\d+))?([acd])(\\d+)(?:,(\\d+))?");
  std::smatch match;
  std::regex_search(t, match, re2);
  cout<<match.size()<<endl;
  cout<<match.str(0)<<endl;

  if (std::regex_search(t, match, re2))
  {
      for (int i=1; i<match.size(); i++)
      {
          result = match.str(i);
          cout<<i<<":"<<result<< " ";
      }
      cout<<endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

The string variable `t` is the string I want to manipulate.
My regular expression

```
(\\d+)(?:,(\\d+))?([acd])(\\d+)(?:,(\\d+))?
```

is working but with strings that do not have the optional subgroups (such as `47a46`, the `match` variable will contain empty elements in the corresponding position of the expected substrings.

For example in the program above the elements of `match` (preceded by their index) are:

```
1:47 2: 3:a 4:46 5:
```

Elements in position `2` and `5` correspond to the optional substring that in this case are not present so I would like `match` to avoid retrieving them so that it would be:

```
1:47 2:a 3:46
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Why not just ignore them ?

Answer (score 1):

I think the best RE for you would be like this:

```
std::regex re2(R"((\d+)(?:,\d+)?([a-z])(\d+)(?:,\d+)?)");
```

- that way it should match all the required groups (but optional)

output:

```
4
47a46
1:47 2:a 3:46
```

Note: the `re2`'s argument string is given in c++11 notation.

EDIT: simplified RE a bit